# "Mi sembra di capire che" + indicativo o congiuntivo?

Tags: verbs, word-choice, subjunctive-mood

Nella frase va bene il tempo indicativo  "hanno" oppure bisogna utilizzare il congiuntivo "abbiano"?

> Mi sembra di capire che tutti quelli che commentano HANNO un italiano impeccabile.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Questione complicata: nel parlato *hanno* è (purtroppo) frequente; c'è *mi sembra* che chiaramente introduce un'opinione, quindi *abbiano* sarebbe molto preferibile.

Comment: Un esempio tratto dall'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/frasi-soggettive_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/): «(49) sembra / pare di capire che non ci siano state vittime».

Comment: Forse quello che sta a complicare un po' la spiegazione è la doppia subordinazione.

Comment: Grazie per le vostre risposte.  "Abbiano" è forse più corretto ma "hanno" è più discorsivo.

Answer (score 5):

Stando anche al link postato da Charo nei commenti ([https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/frasi-soggettive_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/frasi-soggettive_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/)), con particolare riferimento alla sezione "3. Modi del verbo", entrambe le versioni possono essere corrette, a seconda che si esprima una certezza o un'ipotesi:

**Esempio 1**

Ti chiedo di fare qualcosa ma tu non ti muovi:

- "mi sembra di capire che non *abbia* voglia di farlo" (non sono sicuro, magari non mi hai sentito)
- "mi sembra di capire che non *hai* voglia di farlo" (sono ragionevolmente sicuro che mi hai sentito ed hai scelto di ignorare la mia richiesta)

**Esempio 2**

Durante la finale dei mondiali di calcio, sento il vicino di casa esultare:

- "mi sembra di capire che *hanno* segnato un gol" (sono certo che lo hanno fatto)

Ciò detto, nella frase citata nella domanda ("*Mi sembra di capire che tutti quelli che commentano HANNO un italiano impeccabile.*") l'uso dell'indicativo è corretto solo se chi parla conosce tutti quelli che commentano e sa che conoscono l'italiano alla perfezione... eventualità alquanto improbabile.

Answer (score 0):

Se l'oggettiva la facciamo dipendere da "capire", va benissimo l'indicativo! Non è una questione di lingua parlata o scritta.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE! Puoi argomentare un po' di più la tua risposta supportandola con riferimenti a fonti che descrivono la regola grammaticale adatta a questo contesto? Così com'è sembra piuttosto un commento.

Comment: Se consideriamo il costrutto come un'unica proposizione, potrebbe prevalere il senso dell'incertezza,il quale regge il cong.: "Mi sembra di capire che X abbia ragione." Se invece lo trattiamo come due proposizioni,rispettivamente principale e subord. di 1°grado,come dire "mi sembra che io capisca", seguirebbe una subord. di 2°grado,dipendente da "capire/io capisca", la quale reggerebbe l'ind.: "Mi sembra di capire che X ha ragione." Tanto più che non abbiamo un'espressione in cui l'infinito formi un unico predicato con il verbo che lo precede, come avviene per i verbi servili,fraseologici ecc.

Comment: @Alberto, il discorso può valere in generale, con verbi diversi da "capire", ma nel caso specifico non credo che abbia senso considerare due proposizioni separate "mi sembra di capire": se posso aver dubbi, ad esempio, su qualcosa che vedo o che sento ("mi sembra di vedere/sentire che... ma non sono sicuro") non posso avere dubbi su quello che capisco (al massimo posso avere dubbi sulla correttezza di quello che capisco ma non sul fatto di capire in sé). A mio avviso, "mi sembra di capire che..." è più un costrutto retorico che, di fatto equivale a "mi sembra che..." o "capisco che...".